# I want to setup LAMP on ubuntu, but i cant without java

Tags: software-installation, apache2, java

Apparently, apache2 requires java. With the new java updates, I cannot get java 7 even though it requires this. How can I fix this?

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 409 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,541 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,365 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libapr1 amd64 1.5.2-3 [86.0 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1 amd64 1.5.4-1build1 [77.1 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 amd64 1.5.4-1build1 [10.6 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.5.4-1build1 [8,720 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liblua5.1-0 amd64 5.1.5-8ubuntu1 [102 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-bin amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2 [926 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-utils amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2 [81.7 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2 [162 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2 [86.7 kB]
Fetched 1,541 kB in 0s (1,789 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libapr1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 178242 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapr1_1.5.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapr1:amd64 (1.5.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1_1.5.4-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.4-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-ldap:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.4-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblua5.1-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../liblua5.1-0_5.1.5-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblua5.1-0:amd64 (5.1.5-8ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2017-05-22 19:48:53--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.215.133.9, 23.215.133.64
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.215.133.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-05-22 19:48:54--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2600:1408:9000:18b::2d3e, 2600:1408:9000:188::2d3e, 23.218.73.128
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2600:1408:9000:18b::2d3e|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1495497054_20e1c712e565721706307569db286e07 [following]
--2017-05-22 19:48:54--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1495497054_20e1c712e565721706307569db286e07
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.215.133.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-05-22 19:48:55 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libapr1:amd64 (1.5.2-3) ...
Setting up libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.4-1build1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1build1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.4-1build1) ...
Setting up liblua5.1-0:amd64 (5.1.5-8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up apache2-bin (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.2) ...
Enabling module mpm_event.
Enabling module authz_core.
Enabling module authz_host.
Enabling module authn_core.
Enabling module auth_basic.
Enabling module access_compat.
Enabling module authn_file.
Enabling module authz_user.
Enabling module alias.
Enabling module dir.
Enabling module autoindex.
Enabling module env.
Enabling module mime.
Enabling module negotiation.
Enabling module setenvif.
Enabling module filter.
Enabling module deflate.
Enabling module status.
Enabling conf charset.
Enabling conf localized-error-pages.
Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log.
Enabling conf security.
Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
Enabling site 000-default.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Not sure where you got that from, but apache2 most certainly does not require java.

Comment: When installing apache i get the error "openjre-7-installer failed. Apache2 is not installed. Exit code 1"

Comment: Post the full error please (as text).

Comment: I have added these

Comment: Thar she blows(Full output added.)

Comment: Looks apache installed just fine, and apt retried a previous failed installation of openjdk. You should just remove the package if you don't need it.

Comment: Why do you have 409 packages that are not upgraded? I hope this machine is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Will do. Also, I honestly don't know..

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what happened. When ubuntu fails to download something it adds it to a sort of list. When I tried to install apache it worked, but ubuntu also tried the old package. Which threw the error :)

Comment: Can you please add a bit about how you fixed the error?